# How to create Azure Service Bus queue using Java?

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How can I create Azure Service Bus queue using java? There is a dependency which helps me create queue?

Comment: How about [*Azure Service Bus client library for Java*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-servicebus-readme?view=azure-java-stable)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/service-bus?view=azure-java-stable) for Service Bus libraries for Java.
As you want to perform the resource management operation, you need to leverage the [azure-mgmt-servicebus](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22azure-mgmt-servicebus%22) Maven Package as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/service-bus?view=azure-java-stable#libraries-for-resource-management).

You can refer [Manage Service Bus queues](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-java-manage-queue-with-basic-features), [Create and subscribe to Service Bus topics](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-java-manage-publish-subscribe-with-basic-features) sample which has the java code to create the service bus queue.